# python ctypes with dots

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

How do you load a module with ctypes that has dots in the name
example

```
mydll.1.0.dll
```

trying to load it like this

```
ctypes.cdll.mydll.1.0
```

gives a module not found error

I am using python on windows

Comment: Use `ctypes.CDLL('mydll.1.0')`.

Comment: If you're fixed on using the loader it's `ctypes.cdll['mydll.1.0']`. Just note that the loader caches the `CDLL` instance, which caches functions. That can be good or bad depending your use case and whether other packages want to use the same DLL but don't define function prototypes (i.e. `restype`, `argtypes`, `errcheck`, `paramflags`) equivalently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from comments:

> Use ctypes.CDLL('mydll.1.0').
>
> If you're fixed on using the loader it's ctypes.cdll['mydll.1.0']. Just note that the loader caches the CDLL instance, which caches functions. That can be good or bad depending your use case and whether other packages want to use the same DLL but don't define function prototypes (i.e. restype, argtypes, errcheck, paramflags) equivalently.